# Intellij consistently giving unresolved symbol

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, maven-2

I have several kotlin projects, all following intellijs default gradle structure. A couple of them are library projects, and a couple of them are applications. I normally depend on the libraries from the applications by building the librarys as jars, adding them to C:\lib, and then depending on them from my application code, with

```
 flatDir{
     dirs 'C:\lib'
 }
```

listed as a repository. This has always worked great for me. Suddenly in the last day or so, it has ceased to work: the application code still compiles and runs fine, but when I view code in the editor it won't give autcompletes and all references to any of my library code is marked as an unresolved reference. This issue is only present for code from my own libraries which I am depending on in this manner: references to ie guava have no problems.

I have tried everything I can think of: rebuilding the artifacts, invalidating caches and restarting, deleting the .idea folders and reimporting, deleting the projects and making new ones with the same code, restarting the computer, restoring old versions of the .idea folders which I happened to have, and nothing has solved the problem.

I can't write any new code until this problem resolves. My workflow is a bit janky, but I have been using it for a long time and am very happy with it, so I'm super hesitant to abandon it. That said, if nothing else works I'd be open to suggestions of a better way to handle the whole setup.

Note: It occurs to me that the first relevant question would be what has changed when it broke. As far as I am aware, nothing. The library code was recompiled right before everything broke, but I recompile it close to once a day and have never had such an issue before, and I can't think of any other change that would have prompted the issue.

Comment: Not sure what might cause this, but it might be a better idea to just install your libraries to your local Maven repository

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned but I have tried that as well, to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing *all* of the following at the same time. I tried all of them individually and none worked, so its hard to say which ones were necessary and which just happened to be part of the attempt that finally worked, or whether it was all just random chance.

1. Invalidate caches and close intellij.
2. Delete intellij config folder.
3. Uninstall intellij.
4. Delete the .idea folder from all the projects.
5. Restart the computer.
6. Download intellij again, install it, and set it to use 4gb of ram.
7. Reimport all the projects.
8. Publish the jars to my local maven repository instead of using the flatdirs approach I had been using before (Thanks [@Moira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366707/moira), not sure if this was part of the fix but it still seems a better setup)

*edit* Nevermind. This fixed the issue for a couple days and then it regressed randomly. So frustrated.